# how to solve hg commit abort: Unresolve merged conflicts.?

Tags: merge, mercurial

Hello everyone i am facing a serious problem i am going to describe the whole scenario.There is a branch **abc** on bitbucket i have cloned it in my system.

`hg clone -b abc <link>`

After that i have created a local branch **xyz** on which i have started working and use to add commit and push to remote.But now i have switch to **abc** branch and pull all the changes from remote **abc** no conflicts were there:

`hg pull`

`hg update`

`hg update xyz` (checkout to xyz branch)

Then i merge **abc**

`hg merge abc`

Solved all the conflicts and started my work again.

`hg status` shows me the list of all files `M`

`hg add .`

```
hg commit
error: unresolved merged conflicts
```

I dont wanted to lose anything,i have copied all the files in which i have made changes after the merge.Will i lose all the merged changes by this command `hg update -C`.Please help me out to solve this really in a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

After the `hg merge`, use the `hg resolve --all` command, so it will open all conflicts to be resolved.